# Why does the following MySQL query have a syntax error?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT h.hacker_id
     , FIRST(h.name)
  FROM Hackers h 
  JOIN Challenges c 
    ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
  JOIN Difficulty d 
    ON c.difficulty_level = d.difficulty_level
  JOIN Submissions s  
    ON h.hacker_id = s.hacker_id 
   AND c.challenge_id = s.challenge_id
 GROUP  
    BY h.hacker_id
HAVING SUM(s.score = d.score) > 1
 ORDER 
    BY SUM(s.score = d.score) DESC
     , h.hacker_id
```

I'm trying to join a couple of tables and I think the logic is pretty straightforward. However,I got an error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(h.name)". Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There is no FIRST function in MySql.

Comment: ...and FIRST is a reserved word